# wordpress plugin development issue : Generate php pages

Tags: php, wordpress

Does anybody know how to generate pages in wordpress, with php code as a content using a plugin?

For example the; the plugin will create landing pages, without the use of wordpress pages or custom posts. Just in the backend settings, it can add/modify/delete pages.

Thanks,

Comment: Add & Delete is fine. But what do you plan to include when you say edit pages? See editing content using backend is possible but why you trying to edit page using backend?

Comment: I have newbies targeted people that will use the plugin, so instead of creating it and linking it to a normal wordpress page, it will be created automatically.